# Responsive table or absolute table

Tags: html, css

Been playing around with this for a bit and is finally getting to me. At work I was required to make a tic tac toe kind of game using tables. The table is as follows:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="100" width="100" aligh="center" valign="center">X</td>
       ....
       ....
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Was wondering how to make this responsive?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your "work" requires this?

Comment: @j08691 Yup. Every time you click on a box you get asked a multiple choice question that needs to be answered. True being "O" False being "X". User is "O", computer is "X".

Comment: what have you tried? What is the question? Can you post a code example for us to see where the problem is? Do you understand the concept of Responsive and how CSS is used to make things responsive?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on responsive tables. http://a2znotes.blogspot.com/2014/08/making-table-fully-responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try sizing using percentages. Everything is based off of 1/3's.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="33%" width="33%" aligh="center" valign="center">X</td>
       ....
       ....
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Footable](http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/)

Or if you are using bootstrap as a theme, you coudl simply surround your table with

```
<div class="table-responsive">
// your table HTML
</div>
```